# How to enable paging in the Extention JS Simple Grid

Tags: asp.net, json, extjs, grid

I have following grid made in Extension Js, I am using Json to bind my grid. I want to enable the paging in the grid with having some page size say '10' but my paging is not working.

Here is my code,

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var dataStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'Default.aspx/CustomerData', //'web.aspx',
            headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'd'
            }
        },
        fields: [
      { name: 'firstname', type: 'string' },
      { name: 'lastname', type: 'string' },
      { name: 'age', type: 'string' },
      { name: 'phone', type: 'string' }
    ]
    });

    dataStore.load();
    var myGrid1 = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        id: 'customerslist',
        store: dataStore,
        columns: [
        { id: "firstname", header: "First Name", width: 100, dataIndex: "firstname", sortable: true },
        { header: "Last Name", width: 100, dataIndex: "lastname", sortable: true },
        { header: "Age", width: 100, dataIndex: "age", sortable: true },
        { header: "Phone", width: 100, dataIndex: "phone", sortable: true }
      ],
        autoLoad: false,
        stripeRows: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        width: 450,
        height: 300,
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            store: dataStore,  
            dock: 'bottom',
            displayInfo: true
        }],
        renderTo: 'grid1'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try adding pageSize: 10 in store properties

```
var dataStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'Default.aspx/CustomerData', //'web.aspx',
            headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'd'
            }
        },
        fields: [
      { name: 'firstname', type: 'string' },
      { name: 'lastname', type: 'string' },
      { name: 'age', type: 'string' },
      { name: 'phone', type: 'string' }
    ],
        pageSize: 10
    });
```

Comment: Now I have paging but the number of records is not become 10, which should be equal to page size.